# Pushing data coming from Object into an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

What i have here are the first 3 tweets, but i keep having problems to save them into my array. They need to be strings, but i keep getting this:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in 
>   XXX/classes/page.class.php on line 117

```
$arrTweets = array();
foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        array_push($arrTweets, $tweet[$i] - > text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly all you variables, if your design is decent, there should be no need to use the `for` loop:

```
$arrTweets = array();
foreach ($tweets as $tweet){
    array_push($arrTweets, $tweet->text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want only the first 3 tweets, remove the `foreach` and use the `for` loop.

```
$arrTweets = array();

         for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
             array_push($arrTweets, $tweets[$i]->text);
         }
```